# Replace the "add to cart" link in WooCommerce to redirect to vendor's store

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, marketplace, dokan

I have a multivendor marketplace on Wordpress using Dokan and WooCommerce.
We no longer want the sales to be done on our website but directly on our vendors websites.

How can I replace the "add to cart" link in order to redirect the customer to the vendors product page (so directly on the vendor's website) ?

Thanks for your help!

Cheers,

Morgane

At the moment, I don't know where and how to use the specific product page link on the vendor account to change the change the link of the "add to cart" button so that it can be different for each product of each vendor.
We use the single product template and the archive product grid.

Comment: Use external/Affiliate product type option. There you can add link to the product on the vendorwebsite and custom title on the button as you want.

Comment: You're amazing, thank you so much, can't believe it was that simple !!